# variadic vs non variadic function template overloading partial ordering

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In the book *The Complete template guide second edition (chapter 16)*. It was mentioned that one special rule for partial ordering of two matching function templates is that arguments coming from a parameter pack are not allowed to match against a non variadic template function. I was surprised to read that because I have always wrote code similar to the sample below which matches in the final expansion against a non variadic template function.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T && t)
{
    std::cout << "HelloWorld!" << std::endl;
}


template <typename Head, typename ... Tail>
void f(Head && head, Tail && ... tail)
{
    std::cout << head << std::endl;
    f(std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
}


int main()
{
    f(1,2,3);
}
```

**Output**

```
1
2
HelloWorld!
```

Comment: Without knowing the exact statement from the book, I assume you are mixing  overload resolution in general with partial ordering which is used only to disambiguate a call